# KiCAD symbol editor - how to use insert key to duplicate pins with every other number

Tags: kicad, symbol

I'm trying to make this header row in KiCAD. If I place pin 1, and press the insert key, it gets duplicated nicely. The problem is, that pin becomes pin 2, then the next pin 3. I want pin 1,3,5,7,9 etc on left side, and 2,4,6,8,10 on right side. Up to pin 144!

I tried shift+ins, and ctrl+ins. No luck. Can this be done? What is your advice?

[image: What a mess]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd place all the pins in order, alternating left and right, leave the orientation as it is, and then finally go over to the right side, hover above the pin and press `r` twice to rotate it. You can also combine that with placing the pin, by hovering above it, pressing `m` to start moving, and pressing `r` twice while moving.

Selecting multiple pins and rotating them at once also works, but will reverse their order as it also rotates their coordinates around the center of the selection.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to make many of these with different pin counts than you can use one of these generators:

- http://kicad.rohrbacher.net/quicklib.php (A web based generator for simple symbols like your dip style black box symbol)
- https://kipart.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ (A python script to convert spreadsheet descriptions to kicad symbols)
- https://github.com/KiCad/kicad-library-utils/tree/master/schlib/autogen/connector (The generator that creates many of the connector symbols found in the official library)

Comment: Thank you, Rene! That's ingenious. I'll definitely use it next time. This time I did it the hard way.... great links.

Comment: @DrOnline as another trick for symbols/footprints, digikey has some kind of license where a lot of their components (think MCUs, op-amps, dc/dc controllers, that kind of thing) have free ultra-librarian models available (which includes kicad compatible files) as long as you sign up for a digikey account. Probably wouldn't work for a generic pin header, but can save you a lot of time on a 144 pin microcontroller.

Comment: The license of ultra librarian was incompatible with anything you put under open source licenses. (At least it was last time i checked half a year ago. I think we also had a lengthy discussion about that on the forum with somebody claiming to be an employee of ultra librarian. They insisted their license was compatible. We examined it and found many sections contradicting even using their parts inside a project let alone have them in a library shared with the project. Hopefully they updated their license. But i would doubt it as making them compatible would go against their core business.)